# Admob preloaded banner ads android

Tags: android, admob, banner, banner-ads

ok I am playing with ads from one week I have tested all ads like `Native Ads Advanced`,`Interstitial Ads` in these ads i can preload them and show whenever i want to but i am confused about banner ads there is no call back of `onAdImpression()` in banner ad, but in `Interstitial` and `Native Ads Advanced` it is calling. my problem is i want to preload banner ad so when my specific view appear it shows immediately, currently i am loading ad when the view becomes visible and load after some time.i wrote a helper class to preload banner ad, ad is showing fine but there is no logs for if the banner ad had an impression or not can someone help, please ?
i have read that we can show preloaded banner ads but there is no documentation or anything 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/BuczXZG9AeU/KewEg7HFAAAJ

Comment: you should use AdListener.. you can load the Ad anytime you want & then show it when the Ad is loaded, either via `onAdLoaded()` Callback or by checking `bannerAd.isLoaded();`

Comment: @DarShan read my question carefully there is no method `isLoaded()` for banner ad

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that.. banners don't have that method.. alternatively you can hide the Banner Ad untill your View is loaded..